# Associativity rule for integration against fractional Brownian motion

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, brownian-motion

In Itô calculus, it is easy to construct an associativity rule. Namely, if $B_t$ is a Brownian motion and $M_t = \int_0^t X_s dB_s$ for suitable $X_t$, then we have the following associativity rule: $Z_t = \int_0^t Y_s dM_s = \int_0^t Y_s X_s dB_s$. Such a rule can be derived by defining a martingale calculus, or more generally can be extracted from semimartingale calculus.

Is it possible to obtain a similar expression when the integrator $B_t$ is replaced by $B_t^{(H)}$, a fractional Brownian motion with Hurst index $H \neq \frac{1}{2}$?  In this setting, one can't pass through a semimartingale calculus as $B_t^{(H)}$ is no longer a semimartingale. My feeling is that the answer may depend on the choice of $H$, as this affects the construction of the integral.

Comment: If $B_t^{(H)}$ is no longer a semi-martingale, what other nice properties could it have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $H > 1/2$ and assuming that both $X$ and $Y$ have trajectories that are almost surely $\alpha$-Hölder continuous for some $\alpha > 1/2$, there is only one sensible definition of the stochastic integral (Riemann-Stieltjes) and associativity holds since it does so for smooth functions and the integral is stable under mollification. For $H < 1/2$ things are more subtle.

If in addition $H > 1/3$, then the three integrals appearing in your statement are well-defined for $X$ and $Y$ that are controlled rough paths, with the underlying reference rough path being any rough path lift of $B$. (For the definition of the integral of $Y$ against $M$, see Remark 4.11 in [my book with Peter](http://www.hairer.org/notes/RoughPaths.pdf).) Associativity then holds again, as can easily be checked by unpacking the definitions. This is true even if you consider "exotic" integrations by choosing a rough path lift of $B$ other than the canonical one.

For $H \le 1/3$ the same is still true, but it gets more cumbersome to verify: Section 4.5 of that book gives hints on how one would go about it. Note also that for $H \le 1/4$ there is no sensible theory of integration against $B$ anyway, so the point becomes moot then.

Comment: I am confused by the comment on $H\leq 1/4$. In one dimension, you can define a rough path above any fBm trivially. Also, I have seen this paper https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-39/issue-3/A-construction-of-the-rough-path-above-fractional-Brownian-motion/10.1214/10-AOP578.full What was the statement you were trying to make? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @user168590 What I was trying to say is that for $d>1$ there is no known way of lifting fBm with $H \le 1/4$ such that increments of the RP are stationary, time reversible, and only depend on the increments of the underlying fBm in the same interval. With constructions like Nualart-Tindel, Unterberger, or Lyons-Victoir, integrals like $\int_a^b X_s\, dB_s$ will depend on increments of $B$ outside of $[a,b]$ (even if $X$ doesn't) which doesn't seem sensible. Also, none of these constructions is much more "canonical" than any other of a similar type.

Comment: For example, the construction by Nualart-Tindel depends on the choice of representation of the fBm as a moving average.